# How is the spectral response of a camera typically measured?

Tags: sensor, color, color-management, cmos-image-sensor, computational-photography

I cannot find any resources that detail a standardized method of measuring the spectral response of a camera. Does such a standard exist? Does anyone know how to do this?

To give some context, I'm trying to measure the spectral response of a camera module for which the manufacturer has not provided the spectral response curves (I'm not sure why...). I imagine this would involve a monochromator, and maybe an integrating sphere, but again I'm not sure.

I hope this is the correct place to ask this! I think this probably falls within the realm of computational photography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of the ways:
http://www.image-engineering.de/iq-products/iq-tools/measurement-devices/camspec
http://www.image-engineering.de/iq-products/iq-tools/measurement-devices/camspecs-express
I use a monochromator, light sphere, and a photodiode. You can find most of those supplies at Edmund Optics http://www.edmundoptics.com/ and similar shops.
You can also opt for simpler methods using diffraction grids.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there any particular reason you used a photodiode? This could be swapped out with a spectrometer, correct?

Comment: @Clyde W : photodiode is in fact a more precise and simpler way, and something I have a habit to use for the particular purpose of real-time brightness control; but of course you may use a spectrometer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, color sensitivity is often measured and specified in bits.  DxOMark provides one example and incorporates this into their camera ratings.  From [the description of their "Color Depth" test](http://www.dxomark.com/About/Sensor-scores/Use-Case-Scores):

> Color sensitivity
> indicates to what degree of subtlety color nuances can be
> distinguished from one another, often meaning a hit or a miss on a
> Pantone palette. Maximum color sensitivity reports, in bits, the
> number of colors that the sensor is able to distinguish. The higher
> the color sensitivity, the more color nuances that can be
> distinguished.
>
> As with dynamic range, color sensitivity is greatest
> when ISO speed is minimal, and falls rapidly with rising ISO settings.
> DxO Labs has focused on measuring only maximum color sensitivity. A
> color sensitivity of 22bits is excellent, and differences below 1 bit
> are barely noticeable.

Presumably spectral *accuracy*, which it sounds like you may also be concerned with, is just a matter of calibration.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking to measure the spectral responsivity of each colour channel (R, G, B) over a range of wavelengths. I want to produce plots like this: https://www.maxmax.com/images/Cameras/Technical/NikonD200_SpectralResponse.jpg

Sorry, my question isn't terribly clear.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's not something that would concern photographers, but is obviously important for some lab and other scientific applications of camera sensors.  As you note it would be straightforward to sample such a response curve using a monochromator.

Comment: @Clyde W Those plots are from JPEGs and have little to do with colour channels responses.

Comment: @IliahBorg I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. That plot is from the following link: https://www.maxmax.com/spectral_response.htm

It seems like they are looking at each R, G, or B pixel (from the Bayer array) in raw images, not JPEGs. Could you clarify what you are saying?

Comment: @Clyde W : I asked them directly at that time because their curves were far off from sensor specs and my own measurements; and here is the quote from the answer from Dan Llewellyn himself: "Since measuring the response requires taking a picture every 20nm from 300nm to 1000nm, and you need to take both UV-VIS and VIS-IR from separate monochromators, you end up with a lot of pictures.  So far, we have just been taking JPG pictures to keep the file sizes and processing time down."